# Baked normal map leaves dark spot on model

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I’m learning the process of baking normal maps from a sculpt. I’ve created a head model and can get most of the normal texture baked correctly, but am having problems where there are sharp turns in the surface, like on the lips. I’ve created a cage and while it improved the render a bit, I’m still getting a prominent dark spot on the lips. Is there a way to fix this?

[Download blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13ji9MarC0bOVO8ErPahdvkM6eyCOX9Cc)

[image]

Base mesh with face orientation overlay enabled:
[image]

Comment: Most likely the problem with base mesh normals orientation.

Comment: I checked the face normals.  They look correct.

Comment: please provide screenshot of lips in Solid view with *Overlays > Geometry > Face orientation* enabled

Comment: I've added the new image.  I've also provided a link to the .blend file I created.